# how to index last value less than some specified value

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame shown below

```
d = {'one': [1., 2., 3., 4.,5.,6], 'two': [4., 3., 2., 1.,-1,-2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['201305', '201305', '201307', '201307', '201307','201308'])
```

when I was given a string `‘201307’`, I want to get the last value less than than  the  given string `‘201307’` , `'201305'`.

How do I write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html) to drop repeated entries and keeping just the first entry it encounters in conjunction with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to get the integer location of the given label to use as a mask. Deduct 1 from it to obtain it's distinct previous label.

```
>>> idx = df.index.drop_duplicates()
>>> val = idx[idx.get_loc('201307') - 1]    # <------ Insert query here
>>> val
'201305'
```

---

If you want to get the last row before the given `index` string value:

```
>>> df.loc[val].iloc[-1]
one    2.0
two    3.0
Name: 201305, dtype: float64
```

---

Use arg `method=bfill/backfill` to deal with matches not present. It immediately takes the next matched index value for such cases.

```
>>> val = idx[idx.get_loc('201306', method='bfill') - 1]   # Here, '201307' is selected 
>>> val
'201305'
```

Comment: ,your answer is exactly what i want.Thanks a lot.

Comment: may i ask,what if the given string is ‘201306’,how to get '201305'

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't work with strings when numbers are stored as strings. Numeric computation is much faster than string computation. Second, this is an easy problem to solve. Simply sort on index, and check:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df[df.index < int(given_value)].iloc[-1, :]
```

Comment: i really appreciate your first suggestion. However ,I prefer Nickil Maveli's answer on the second problem.Thanks a lot.